# how to get "year" from string values in jquery or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

i got the string like this :

```
string1 = "Feb 2010 " 
string2 =  "On Going"
string3 =  "may 1990 "
string4 = "jun 1990 "
string5 =  "On Going "
```

i am trying to write one funcation like this :

```
function getyear(val)
{
    return val;
}
```

so if i pass string1 , it should give me "2010",  and if pass string2 ,it should be give me **"Now"**,

how it possible using jquery? or java script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a regular expression such as:

```
/\d{4}/.test(val) ? val.replace(/^[^\d]*(\d{4}).*$/, '$1') : 'Now';
```

```js
var string = [ "Feb 2010 ", "On Going", "may 1990 ", "jun 1990 ", "On Going "];

function getyear(val)
{
    return /\d{4}/.test(val) ? val.replace(/^[^\d]*(\d{4}).*$/, '$1') : 'Now';
}

$.each( string, function(i,v) {
  $('.out').append( (i+1) + ':\t' + getyear( v ) + '\n');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre class="out"></pre>
```

Comment: Great @delmric. See demo too for usage.

Comment: Sorry sir, i need to change my question, please give me updated answer

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could do something like this:

```
function getyear(val){
    var split = val.split(" ");
    for (i = 0; i < split.length; i++){
        if(parseInt(split[i], 10)) return split[i];
    }
    return val;
}
```

This will return the first int found, and if it can't find one it will return the passed value. That way it returns 'on going' when there is no year, no matter where in the string. You can also pass 'The year I want is 2010' and it should return 2010.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```js
string1 = "Feb 2010 "
string2 = "On Going"
string3 = "may 1990 "
string4 = "jun 1990 "
string5 = "On Going "

function getyear(val) {
    var newVal = "Now";
    return val == "On Going" ? newVal : val.substr(val.indexOf(' ') + 1);
}

console.log(getyear(string1)); //gives 2010
console.log(getyear(string2)); //gives Now
```

Note that if there is no space will return full string

Answer (score 1):

```js
var string = "hello 2014";
var l = string.substr(string.length - 4);
if(l.charAt(l.length - 4) == '1' ||l.charAt(l.length - 4) == '2')
  alert(l.slice(-4));
else
  alert("Now");
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. using reg exp

```js
function myFunction( val) {
     // val = "year 2014";
    var patt1 = /[0-9]{4}/g;
    
   if ( str.match(patt1) )
        return ( str.match(patt1) );
   else
        return val;
    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest:

```
function getYear (str) {
    var year = (/\b\d{4}\b/).exec(str);
  return year === null ? 'Now' : year[0];
}
```

```js
function getYear (str) {
    var year = (/\b\d{4}\b/).exec(str);
  return year === null ? 'Now' : year[0];
}

var specimins = ["Feb 2010 ","On Going","may 1990 ", "jun 1990 ","On Going "];

specimins.forEach(function (string, index) {
  console.log(index + ': ' + getYear(string));
});
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).
- [JavaScript Conditional ('Ternary') operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).
- [JavaScript Regular Expressions ('RegExp')](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`RegExp.exec()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec).